# Encryption on ESP-32 Async Webserver

Tags: json, cryptography, esp32

I am currently trying to implement a save method for someone to change the Mode of an ESP-32 from Accesspoint Mode to Station mode via a Webpage on an asynchronous Webserver. The data gets put into a JSON string and sent to the ESP-32 where it gets written in a JSON file, and later read out of again and used to connect to a network with.

```js
else {
  IP = "NULL";
  Netmask = "NULL";
  Gateway = "NULL";
  var data = {ssid:ssid, password:password, IP:IP, Netmask:Netmask, Gateway:Gateway};
  console.log(data);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url ="/settings";

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200) {
      console.log(xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

The problem with this method is that someone who is spying on the network could just grab the JSON string as it is and gain access to the network the ESP-32 is trying to connect itself with. Thats why I want to implement a lightweight way to encrypt this string before it gets sent, and to locally encrypt it, using Javascript on the webpage. The Problem is that, the moment I execute this operation, I am not online, so grabbing a script from the outside, e.g. CryptoJS is not possible. I'm stuck on this for weeks now and have no idea how to do this.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t store a copy of, say, CryptoJS, on the ESP32 and serve it via the async web server to the client that uploads the data you’re trying to protect, or just include it in that clients web page instead of linking to it?

Comment: I was afraid the esp would run out of space if I put that in there aswell, because in order to decrypt it, I'd also need a crypto library for the esp32, which probably takes up a lot of space. Do you have a source where I can get the cryptoJS files? I'd at least try it.

Answer (score 0):

The de-facto way of protecting against eavesdropping is to implement HTTPS.

ESP32 has built-in TLSv1.3 support thanks to [wolfssl](https://github.com/espressif/esp-wolfssl).

Below is an example HTTPS server taken from the official ESP-IDF [examples](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/https_server/simple).

You will need a server certificate to run it. You can use generate a self-signed certificate with openssl, or if you have a valid DNS name, get a CA-signed one e.g. from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/). Even a self-signed cert with TLS 1.2+ will protect against sniffing.

```
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <esp_event.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <esp_system.h>
#include <nvs_flash.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "protocol_examples_common.h"

#include <esp_https_server.h>

/* A simple example that demonstrates how to create GET and POST
 * handlers and start an HTTPS server.
*/

static const char *TAG = "example";


/* An HTTP GET handler */
static esp_err_t root_get_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
    httpd_resp_send(req, "<h1>Hello Secure World!</h1>", HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);

    return ESP_OK;
}

static const httpd_uri_t root = {
    .uri       = "/",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = root_get_handler
};


static httpd_handle_t start_webserver(void)
{
    httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    // Start the httpd server
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting server");

    httpd_ssl_config_t conf = HTTPD_SSL_CONFIG_DEFAULT();

    extern const unsigned char cacert_pem_start[] asm("_binary_cacert_pem_start");
    extern const unsigned char cacert_pem_end[]   asm("_binary_cacert_pem_end");
    conf.cacert_pem = cacert_pem_start;
    conf.cacert_len = cacert_pem_end - cacert_pem_start;

    extern const unsigned char prvtkey_pem_start[] asm("_binary_prvtkey_pem_start");
    extern const unsigned char prvtkey_pem_end[]   asm("_binary_prvtkey_pem_end");
    conf.prvtkey_pem = prvtkey_pem_start;
    conf.prvtkey_len = prvtkey_pem_end - prvtkey_pem_start;

    esp_err_t ret = httpd_ssl_start(&server, &conf);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Error starting server!");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Set URI handlers
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Registering URI handlers");
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &root);
    return server;
}

static void stop_webserver(httpd_handle_t server)
{
    // Stop the httpd server
    httpd_ssl_stop(server);
}

static void disconnect_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                               int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    httpd_handle_t* server = (httpd_handle_t*) arg;
    if (*server) {
        stop_webserver(*server);
        *server = NULL;
    }
}

static void connect_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                            int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    httpd_handle_t* server = (httpd_handle_t*) arg;
    if (*server == NULL) {
        *server = start_webserver();
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    static httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

    /* Register event handlers to start server when Wi-Fi or Ethernet is connected,
     * and stop server when disconnection happens.
     */

#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_WIFI
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &connect_handler, &server));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED, &disconnect_handler, &server));
#endif // CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_WIFI
#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_ETHERNET
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP, &connect_handler, &server));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(ETH_EVENT, ETHERNET_EVENT_DISCONNECTED, &disconnect_handler, &server));
#endif // CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_ETHERNET

    /* This helper function configures Wi-Fi or Ethernet, as selected in menuconfig.
     * Read "Establishing Wi-Fi or Ethernet Connection" section in
     * examples/protocols/README.md for more information about this function.
     */
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(example_connect());
}
```

ESP32 can even do Websocket over SSL - see [wss_server](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/https_server/wss_server) example.

Comment: This is architecturally the correct answer but in practical terms it may be very difficult to make work due to certificate management issues.

Comment: letsencrypt certificates are valid for 90 days. So you would need an automation process indeed.

Comment: There are acme clients that can run natively on esp32, e.g. [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/esp32-acme-client/) one. I haven't tried it myself yet as I simply use a self-signed cert. Another way to get a free CA-signed cert is via cloudflare (it also supports self-signed origin certs). You can even use it as a dyn dns solution by updating your IP via CF API.